# How to subscribe to both url and params in ActivatedRoute?

Tags: angular

`activatedRoute.url.subscribe` returns a list of `urlsegments` whenever url changes. `activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe` returns an object of `queryParams` whenever it changes.

How can I subscribe to both, so in the callback I can access to both the latest url and the latest params?

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fork join

```
 Observable.forkJoin(activatedRoute.url, activatedRoute.queryParams)
    .subscribe(( a, b ) => { both have resolved here });
```

See: [RxJs:forkJoin](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md)